# 500 internal server error in woocommerce authorize plugin

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, authorize.net

I am using an net aim authorize plugin for woocommerce. I have an account in authroize payment site. I also made the test credential eg API ID and API Transaction key , selected the test environment and transaction type to charge and authroize also few times when i am testing the checkout by using the following credit card number
4222222222222, 4007000000027 which can be found on the below url

http://community.developer.authorize.net/t5/Integration-and-Testing/Test-Credit-Card-Numbers/td-p/7653

On clicking the button it is showing 500 internal server error. i dont know why it is happening but it is showing the same error over again and again. My Curl option is also enable

Comment: Look into your server logs.

Comment: it is saying Class 'WC_Authorize_Net_CIM' not found in public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-gateway-authorize-net-aim/includes/api/class-wc-authorize-net-aim-api.php

Comment: Well then I guess you found out your issue. You have a missing class here.

Comment: Yeah i also think so. Maybe the plugin is not complete that is why it is showing that error